# Redmine: Issue to mail with Windows

Tags: redmine, bitnami

I need to activate the option:`create issue via mail`, but I don't know how to do it.

I read the documentation but I don't understand it. I use bitnami to work with redmine on Windows platform.

Update:

I think i more closer now but when i run:

```
C:\Bitnami\redmine-3.2.3-0\apps\redmine\htdocs>rake redmine:email:receive_imap RAILS_ENV="production" host=imap.gmail.com port=993 ssl=true username=xxxxxxx@xxx.x password=xxxxx
```

it returns me.

```
 OpenSSL::SSL::SSLError: SSL_connect returned=1 errno=0 state=SSLv3 read server certificate B: certificate verify failed
```

I' d change imap.rb as I read on another post I also update ruby gems and nothing always the same error. I changed and now don't give any error.
And I set Gmail accept insecure programa

Comment: Hi, Bitnami developer here. Have you configured the email settings of Redmine? You will need to edit the file at installdir/apps/redmine/htdocs/config/configuration.yml  and set the correct credentials for your mail account. You will find more information about it here: https://docs.bitnami.com/installer/apps/redmine/#how-to-configure-outbound-email-settings

Comment: Thanks Jota. But we need to transform a mail to issue on Windows machines. We have the mails corrrectly but i dont' how to transform mail to issue.

Comment: Hi Emilio. Just a quick note to let you know that we're trying to reproduce the issue. We'll update this post when having more information.

Comment: Jota Thanks a lot

Comment: Were steps provided for windows platform ? (how to configure email setting to convert emails to issues on windows platform)

Answer (score 2):

this issue was reported in the Redmine forum

http://www.redmine.org/boards/1/topics/33669.

It seems you need to create a configuration file at `config/initializers/` with the following content.

`require 'openssl' 
OpenSSL::SSL::VERIFY_PEER = OpenSSL::SSL::VERIFY_NONE`

Please also try to run the rake command using `bundle exec`.

Regards,
Jota

Comment: Hi Jota can you please tell me the exact steps to be followed for  Windows platform.(Bitnami Stack)